# Visual Studio's JavaScript code formatting in for loops

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, code-formatting

The default code formatting for JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012 does this with `for` loops:

```
for (var a = b; a < c; a++)
{
}
for (var a = b() ; a < c; a++)
{
}
for (var a = b; a < c() ; a++)
{
}
for (var a = (b) ; a < (c) ; a++)
{
}
```

Notice the spaces after `b()`, `c()`, `(b)`, and `(c)`.

Where is the option to remove those spaces, or does VS just have a phobia of frowning winky faces?

`);`

Comment: none of the spacing settings under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript > Formatting > Spacing` lets you disable this. Seems like it is baked in and there is no setting for it (yet).

Comment: On the assumption that this is a bug, I've opened an [issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788535/code-formatter-inserts-extra-space-between-closing-parenthesis-and-semicolon-in-for-loop-in-javascript).

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. It's more like a missing feature or setting. Someone at their team could have thought this would improve readability and everyone would love it

Comment: I've never seen inconsistency improve readability. And I most certainly don't love it.

Comment: Still present in VS2015

Answer (score 1):

Use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It's a brilliant tool for C#, and it also has really good JavaScript support - including a JS Lint plugin which will allow you to enforce JS code conventions / styles.

It's not free, though - but it'll make your code more consistent and higher quality.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be an option to change this, but if there is, it's likely here (choose the relevant language):

[image: Visual Studio Options]